# Сериализация С++ объектов в Java объекты и обратно

Tags: java, c++, сериализация

Недавно прочитал [статью](https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/220359/)
на хабре, в которой было сказано следующее:

> Чтобы у нас работала система посылки сообщений и удаленный вызов процедур, нам нужен клиент-серверный протокол и способ сериализации/десериализации объектов. Напомню, что у нас есть необходимость пересылать команды и данные с клиента на сервер, т.е. из C++ в Java и обратно. Для этого мы по Java-классам генерируем их копии в C++, а также генерируем методы для сериализации и десериализации объектов в байтовый поток. Код для сериализации встраивается прямо внутрь классов и обращается к полям класса напрямую. Таким образом, сервер не тратит процессорное время на обход классов с помощью reflection.

Может кто-нибудь поподробнее осветить этот момент и как вообще это можно реализовать?

Comment: Гуглите protobuf, grpc

Comment: В следующем же абзаце той статьи и описано, как это реализовано. А ещё в конце статьи есть "Как обычно, на все вопросы отвечаем в комментариях."